# windows xp periodically loses network shares

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares

we have a LAN of windows xp machines all in the same workgroup. Most of the machines have several shared directories, with RW access from anyone on the network. Mapped drives are not being used.

The problem is that every so often, for any given machine, the shares disappear from the "My Network Places": the workgroup still appears, but has no shares listed. Sometimes it returns of its own accord, and/or after mapping a network drive. It's driving me bananas.

Anyone know what's going on, and how to fix it?

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq): *"Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already "signed" with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page."*

Comment: Is this happening on all your machines just one in particular ? To me it looks more of an issue of the router/switch you are using . Try changing updating its firmware or replacing it.

Comment: @Shark: I'd hesitate to say all, but certainly on more than one. The router is brand new, and the firmware is up-to-date. I use the same router on our home network with no problems